# iOS get current and previous selected UITableViewCells from cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Tags: ios, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

So basically what I am doing now is expanding my cells by selecting on them and using heightForRowAtIndexPath to change their height and if I select on it again or select a different cell those cells will expand or go back to their normal size.

However, upon the cell expanding I have some extra data to show in the expanded section, change the background color of the cell and set some other properties that I have defined in my tableviewcell subclass. So as an example when the cell is in its normal height the background will be light green. When its expanded it needs to be white. I set my tableviewcell subclass property (a BOOL) so that when its time to loop through the cells again (cellforRowatindexpath) i can update these properties as needed. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a way to get the current cell thats been selected in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Here is the relevant code below. Keep in mind that I want to keep track of the current cell selected and the previous cell (if different from the current one) so that i can update both cells properties. Only one cell can be expanded at a time. When the current cell is selected and expanded the previous one(if applicable) will contract back to normal height. My configureCell method is just there to assign the properties based its BOOL property.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell configureCell:self.item[indexPath.row] isCollapsed:cell.isCollapsed];

    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MyCustomCell *currentCell;
    MyCustomCell *previousCell;

    self.currentSelectedIndex = indexPath;
    //assign previous and current if previous is nil
    if(!self.previousSelectedIndex){
        self.previousSelectedIndex = self.currentSelectedIndex;
        currentCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.currentSelectedIndex];
        currentCell.isCollapsed = NO;
    }
    //we have tapped the same cell as before
    else if(self.previousSelectedIndex == self.currentSelectedIndex){
        previousCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.previousSelectedIndex];
        previousCell.isCollapsed = YES;
        self.previousSelectedIndex = self.currentSelectedIndex = nil;
    }
    //if they aren't equal, then collapse the previous selected cell
    //and expand the current selected cell
    else{
        previousCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.previousSelectedIndex];
        previousCell.isCollapsed = YES;

        currentCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.currentSelectedIndex];
        currentCell.isCollapsed = NO;
        self.previousSelectedIndex = self.currentSelectedIndex;

    }

    [tableView beginUpdates];
  if(self.currentSelectedIndex){
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[self.currentSelectedIndex, self.previousSelectedIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}

    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

So, obviously my current and previous cell will be trashed once we leave this method since they are local but I am struggling with how to:

a. reload the cells which would cause cellForRowAtIndexPath to execute again(this works when trying to use reloadRows - but maybe I'm doing that wrong)
b.once cellForRowAtIndex starts going through the cells how to capture the currentCell and the previousCell so that i can update its content as I described above. [dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myIdentifier] just gets a new cell which I do not want obviously.

The cells expand and contract fine so thats not an issue.

Comment: Whether a cell should be collapsed or not is something that your controller should tell your view, not something you should be asking your view as you are doing here: [cell configureCell:self.item[indexPath.row] isCollapsed:cell.isCollapsed]; Either have a property in your model class (if you feel like it's something inherent to that object) or you can say if indexPath isEqual self.currentSelectedIndex  [cell configureCell:self.item[indexPath.row] isCollapsed:NO]; else [cell configureCell:self.item[indexPath.row] isCollapsed:YES];

Comment: yeah i have definitely made that a lot more complicated. I should just keep track of the current index and anything else not the current index will be collapsed. Im having some trouble getting cellForRow and heightForRow to be in sync but I'm working through it.